# How to make perfect power algorithm more efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def isPP(n):
  pos = [int(i) for i in range(n+1)]
  pos = pos[2:] ##to ignore the trivial n** 1 == n case
  y = []
  for i in pos:
      for it in pos:
          if i** it == n:
              y.append((i,it))
              #return list((i,it))
      #break
  if len(y) <1:
      return None
  else:
      return list(y[0])
```

Which works perfectly up until ~2000, since I'm storing far too much in memory. What can I do to make it work efficiently for large numbers (say, 50000 or 100000). I tried to make it end after finding one case, but my algorithm is still far too inefficient if the number is large.

Any tips?

Comment: You should realize it's not a power of `2` long before you get to the point of checking `2 ** 99999 == 100000`....

Comment: Never considered to break if i ** it > n.

Comment: @nodel, you should use the log. I've written an answer explaining the code and logic. See if that answers the question and requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A number *n* is a perfect power if there exists a *b* and *e* for which *b*^*e* = *n*. For instance 216 = 6^3 = 2^3 * 3^3 is a perfect power, but 72 = 2^3 * 3^2 is not.

The trick to determining if a number is a perfect power is to know that, if the number is a perfect power, then the exponent *e* must be less than log2 *n*, because if *e* is greater then 2^*e* will be greater than *n*. Further, it is only necessary to test prime *e*s, because if a number is a perfect power to a composite exponent it will also be a perfect power to the prime factors of the composite component; for instance, 2^15 = 32768 = 32^3 = 8^5 is a perfect cube root and also a perfect fifth root.

The function `isPerfectPower` shown below tests each prime less than log2 *n* by first computing the integer root using Newton's method, then powering the result to check if it is equal to *n*. Auxiliary function `primes` compute a list of prime numbers by the Sieve of Eratosthenes, `iroot` computes the integer *k*th-root by Newton's method, and `ilog` computes the integer logarithm to base *b* by binary search.

```
def primes(n): # sieve of eratosthenes
    i, p, ps, m = 0, 3, [2], n // 2
    sieve = [True] * m
    while p <= n:
        if sieve[i]:
            ps.append(p)
            for j in range((p*p-3)/2, m, p):
                sieve[j] = False
        i, p = i+1, p+2
    return ps

def iroot(k, n): # assume n > 0
    u, s, k1 = n, n+1, k-1
    while u < s:
        s = u
        u = (k1 * u + n // u ** k1) // k
    return s

def ilog(b, n): # max e where b**e <= n
    lo, blo, hi, bhi = 0, 1, 1, b
    while bhi < n:
        lo, blo, hi, bhi = hi, bhi, hi+hi, bhi*bhi
    while 1 < (hi - lo):
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        bmid = blo * pow(b, (mid - lo))
        if n < bmid: hi, bhi = mid, bmid
        elif bmid < n: lo, blo = mid, bmid
        else: return mid
    if bhi == n: return hi
    return lo

def isPerfectPower(n): # x if n == x ** y, or False
    for p in primes(ilog(2,n)):
        x = iroot(p, n)
        if pow(x, p) == n: return x
    return False
```

There is further discussion of the perfect power predicate at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/03/13/perfect-power-predicate/).

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, it's far easier to iteratively check "Does it have a square root? Does it have a cube root? Does it have a fourth root? ..." You will very quickly get to the point where putative roots have to be between `1` and `2`, at which point you can stop.

Comment: I tried to implement this but in python, 1000**(1/3) =9.999999999999998. How would I work around this while keeping the integrity of solution (ignoring false matches)?

Comment: @nodel: Use an exact method to tell if it has a cube root.

Comment: @nodel Instead of `x**(1/n)`, try using `integer_nthroot(x, n)` with `from sympy.core.power import integer_nthroot`: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.power.integer_nthroot

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way would be implementing this "hack":

```
import math

def isPP(n):
    range = math.log(n)/math.log(2)
    range = (int)(range)
    result = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        if(i<=1):
            continue
        exponent = (int)(math.log(n)/math.log(i))
        for j in [exponent-1, exponent, exponent+1]:
            if i ** j == n:
                result.append([i,j])
    return result

print isPP(10000)
```

Result:

```
[[10,4],[100,2]]
```

The hack uses the fact that:

```
if log(a)/log(b) = c,
    then power(b,c) = a
```

Since this calculation can be a bit off in floating points giving really approximate results, exponent is checked to the accuracy of `+/- 1`.

You can make necessary adjustments for handling corner cases like `n=1, etc.`

Answer (score 1):

a relevant improvement would be:

```
import math

def isPP(n):

        # first have a look at the length of n in binary representation
        ln = int(math.log(n)/math.log(2)) + 1

        y = []
        for i in range(n+1):
                if (i <= 1):
                        continue
                # calculate max power

                li = int(math.log(i)/math.log(2))
                mxi = ln / li + 1
                for it in range(mxi):
                        if (it <= 1):
                                continue
                        if i ** it == n:
                                y.append((i,it))
                                # break if you only need 1

        if len(y) <1:
                return None
        else:
                return list(y[0])
```